# How do I aggregate text values into a single record

Tags: sql, postgresql

For example a site traffic log

```
User  Site
1     Example.com
2     Example.com
3     Google.com
```

I want to ask the database "Give me a view of all the users that visited each site" and output something like this

```
Site           Ids
Example.com    1,2
Google.com     3,
```

I don't mind if it requires some python or pl/pgsql. Any ideas that would lead me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array_agg` method defined [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html). Like

```
with a (user_id, site) as (values(1, 'Example.com'), (2, 'Example.com'), (3, 'Google.com'))
select site, array_agg(user_id) 
from a
group by 1;

    site     | array_agg 
-------------+-----------
 Google.com  | {3}
 Example.com | {1,2}
```